# Understanding the phototransistor

Tags: transistors, npn, photodiode, phototransistor

I am trying to learn how a phototransistor works, and I have made a schematic to show how I understand the photo-diode and NPN transistor to be linked in a phototransistor.

I think that when light intensity reaches a certain level, the photodiode should conduct current and the bulb should light up. Is this correct? I am also wondering whether there would need to be a connection between the photodiode and the emitter, as shown with a question mark in the image below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwt3Kr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The image below is how I image the electron flow should be when the photodiode conducts:

[image]

For reference, this is a less detailed depiction of the design I would like to achieve with the above schematic:

[image]

Comment: This is so big bunch of radical misconceptions that the full corrective explanation would be long. Are you sure this is not a bad joke?

Comment: Related [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565304/understanding-how-a-npn-transistor-works)

Comment: I agree with @user287001

Comment: Not a bad joke, I must just be misunderstanding. Would you mind explaining where I have gone wrong? And @AJN I can delete the previous question as this is indeed a clarification of the previous one, although they are slightly different.

Comment: In the first figure, both the ends of the photo diode are shorted. This means that any circulating current through that loop cannot contribute any current to the base of the transistor. Secondly, the transistor junctions may not be properly biased to the required voltages. For an NPN transistor, the emitter is usually connected to a lower potential than the collector.

Comment: There is no photodiode "connected" to a phototransistor, the base-emitter and base-collector junctions of the transistor form photodiodes.

Comment: Don't delete the previous question since you have already accepted an answer to that. Better to leave it alone i think.

Comment: You've also drawn your transistor in your schematic with the emitter and collector swapped.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks, that makes sense regarding the base-emitter junction. How come the collector and emitter are the wrong way around?

Comment: @OrlandoAlexander You tell me--you're the one who labelled the emitter as "collector" and vice versa!

Comment: @Hearth I labelled the collector as such because that is the side of the NPN transistor which the electron current flows out of the transistor and the emitter as such because that's the side the electron current enters the transistor. Is that not correct?

Comment: @OrlandoAlexander You have the electron current going in the opposite direction it should (rather, your battery is backwards, so the transistor will be in reverse active mode). The side of the symbol with the arrow on it is always the emitter.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for your help. Could you have a look at my answer to the question - if it is incorrect I will delete/amend it.

Comment: Like I said, there is no photodiode involved, the transistor itself is photosensitive.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I am just breaking it down into its core components...

Comment: Also, @user287001, let's try to be a bit more friendly to newcomers who are interested in actual understanding? If they didn't have some kind of misconception or misunderstanding, they wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @Hearth OK. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image presents normal useful voltage polarities and current directions for NPN transistor in a circuit:

[image]

I guess you know that base current can be increased by reducing the resistance R1 or by increasing the voltage of BAT1.

The collector current in a loop which contains a voltage source BAT2, a load and the BE-section of transistor Q1, can be controlled by changing the current in the base loop.

Normally the collector current can be tens or hundreds times bigger than the base current due the current gain in the transistor, but not higher than the voltage of BAT2 and the resistance of the load allow by Ohm's law.

Think that in phototransistor light (actually carrier generation in the semiconductor molecular structure caused by photons) replaces the base current, there's no need for the base current loop.

I do not recommend a beginner starts to keep a circuit which has photodiode and ordinary transistor as an exact equivalent of phototransistor. The latter is probably designed for certain performance which is difficult to achieve by connecting a photodiode and ordinary transistor and simply the light affects to the parts of a specially shaped transistor, there's no separate photodiode in a phototransistor.

In addition too well adopted not so accurate equivalent circuit can harm learning the real semiconductor physics of the operation of a component, if he one day starts semiconductor engineering studies.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct schematic and diagram of electron/conventional current flow according to the advice others have given. If it is not, I will delete this answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUIuVK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Photodiode should go to the collector, not the emitter.

Comment: @KD9PDP I have edited the schematic - is that correct now?

Comment: I can't really say this is *wrong*, but I imagine it's likely to be misleading if you're interested in the physics of the device beyond just using it as a switch. In particular, I think this misrepresents how nonlinear phototransistors are when compared to photodiodes.

Comment: If, however, you're just interested in operation as a light-sensitive switch, this is likely a good enough understanding. Just be aware that the actual physics are more complicated! (and an area of relatively specialized study that I never studied, so I can't explain exactly how. Might be worth looking into if you're interested, though!)

Comment: @Hearth OK sure! Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: yes, this is "better." I was going to say the same thing as others had said. If you want to understand how it works as a device, you have to go down to the device level (NPN, carriers, photo generation of electron hole pairs). But as a circuit, this should give you a good enough model.

Comment: @KD9PDP I understand how photo-diodes work by themselves in terms of electron-hole pair generation, but when it comes to a transistor, where does this process take place? Is it in the base substance?

Comment: No problem, happy to help people learn about things that interest them! Don't take my word as law, since I've not done extensive study of the subject, but photogeneration should occur in the entire exposed area of the transistor die, down under the surface by an amount dependent on the semiconductor's optical properties. Most places, the generated carriers would recombine before doing anything useful, but close enough to either the base-emitter or base-collector junction and they would become photocurrent.

Comment: @Hearth I may be wrong here, but wouldn't photocurrent only be generated if the photon strikes an atom near the base-collector junction as the base-emitter junction will be forward biased and so have no electric field?

Comment: If it strikes the base-emitter junction, I suppose you'd get a photovoltaic effect, which, if it's biased in the way phototransistors usually are (how it's biased in your circuit), would just recombine, yes. You could bias it for use in the photovoltaic mode, if your phototransistor has its base externally accessible, but I don't think that would be any different from using a photodiode in photovoltaic mode. (Of course, you could also use the phototransistor in reverse active mode, but that would have very low gain. Possibly greater linearity though? I'm not sure.)

Comment: Photodiodes work via generation of EHPs in the depletion region that drift in depletion regions, then minority carriers diffuse in the N and P regions. You basically are modulating the reverse saturation current. Phototransistors work like BJTs in that the EHP generation in the base increases carrier injection from the emitter. So in photodiodes, it's a direct effect, in Pohototransistors, it's kind of an indirect effect that works in a similar way as base current works.

Comment: @KD9PDP OK, thanks that makes sense. One question: as minority carriers can pass over reverse biases, why don't free electrons flow across the reverse biased base-collector junction in a phototransistor when no light shines? Is it simply that the electrons don't have enough energy or is it something else?

Comment: A tiny number of carriers flow across the reverse biased base-collector junction when no light shines. Those are electrons that have enough energy (from being at some temperature above 0 Kelvin) to diffuse over the reversed biased BC junction. So BC is reversed biased with a tiny current. Because of that tiny current, BE is slightly forward biased with a tiny forward current.